# Is video streaming over IoT protocols feasible?

Tags: video-streaming, mqtt, iot, coap

Can Video streaming (low bitrates like 50 Kbps ) could be done over IoT protocols  like CoAP/MQTT with much better performances compared to HTTP/RTP or TCP/UDP streaming? Or underlying video streaming architecture does not help the use case using CoAP/MQTT. I am expecting some good resources or examples to support or not support my question. I asked this question because I could not find good resource on video streaming over IoT protocols. Please help.

Answer (score 28):

MQTT is specialized in low-bandwidth, high-latency environments, it is an ideal protocol for machine-to-machine (M2M) communication. http://mqtt.org/
Streaming video requires a continuous data flow.
You could implement video over MQTT as it supports binary payload http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718026 but it is not what it was designed for.
Nothing prevent you to implement a multi-protocol device. MQTT for sensor streaming and TCP/UDP for streaming.

Answer (score 9):

I think for MQTT @danvy answered your question.

For CoAP: it's not a good idea, CoAP was designed for low throughput and lossy networks it will be quite useless for video streaming;
look at RTP or RSTP

Comment: Did you get a satisfying answer?